# Typescript is not assignable error when accessing xState types

Tags: typescript, xstate

Hi al I'm having a small typing problem with a component I'm trying to fix:

```
interface ChildrenProps {
  exit: (force?: boolean) => void;
  state: StateValue;
}
interface Props {
  // https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html
  children: (childrenProps: ChildrenProps) => {};
  close: () => void;
  isOpen: boolean;
  state: StateValue;
}
const ModalDialog: React.FC<Props> = function (props) {
  const { children, close, isOpen } = props;
  const layers = useContext(LayersContext);
  const [state, send] = useMachine(modelDialogMachine, {
    actions: {
      close,
    },
  });
  ...
  const childrenProps = { state: state.value, exit: sendExitEvent };

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <ModalDialogContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <Backdrop className={state.value} onClick={handleBackdropClick}>
        <Dialog onClick={handleDialogClick}>{children(childrenProps)}</Dialog>
      </Backdrop>
    </ModalDialogContext.Provider>,
    container,
  );
};
```

At  `<Backdrop className={state.value} onClick={handleBackdropClick}>` I'm getting:

```
 Type 'StateValue' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'StateValueMap' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", DefaultTheme, {}, never>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", DefaultTheme, {}, never>, string | ... 1
```

Where `StateValue` are types from `import { StateValue } from 'xstate'` the `xstate` state machine library.

The classname is used to switch between styles:

```
export const Backdrop = styled.div`
  &.entering {
  ...
```

How can I resolve this typing error?Hi al I'm having a small typing problem with a component I'm trying to fix:

```
interface ChildrenProps {
  exit: (force?: boolean) => void;
  state: StateValue;
}
interface Props {
  // https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html
  children: (childrenProps: ChildrenProps) => {};
  close: () => void;
  isOpen: boolean;
  state: StateValue;
}
const ModalDialog: React.FC<Props> = function (props) {
  const { children, close, isOpen } = props;
  const layers = useContext(LayersContext);
  const [state, send] = useMachine(modelDialogMachine, {
    actions: {
      close,
    },
  });
  ...
  const childrenProps = { state: state.value, exit: sendExitEvent };

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <ModalDialogContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <Backdrop className={state.value} onClick={handleBackdropClick}>
        <Dialog onClick={handleDialogClick}>{children(childrenProps)}</Dialog>
      </Backdrop>
    </ModalDialogContext.Provider>,
    container,
  );
};
```

At  `<Backdrop className={state.value} onClick={handleBackdropClick}>` I'm getting:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | "style" | ... 252 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, "ref" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "ref" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'StateValue' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'StateValueMap' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", DefaultTheme, {}, never>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", DefaultTheme, {}, never>, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>', gave the following error.
```

Where `StateValue` are types from `import { StateValue } from 'xstate'` the `xstate` state machine library.

The classname is used to switch between styles:

```
export const Backdrop = styled.div`
  &.entering {
  ...
```

If I `console.log` the `state.value` I do get strings:

```
ModalDialog.js:79 exited
ModalDialog.js:79 entering
ModalDialog.js:79 entered
```

Typing for `StateValue` and `StateValueMap`

```
export declare type StateValue = string | StateValueMap;

export interface StateValueMap {
    [key: string]: StateValue;
}
```

How can I resolve this typing error?

Answer (score 0):

If you know it'll be a string, you can type cast it: `className={state.value as string}`. Just bear in mind that more complex machines can return an object (i.e. if you have a parallel machine) so the cast is only valid if you don't plan to ever need the `StateValueMap` variant. If you do, you can run into the  `Objects are not valid as a React child` error at run time if you, for example, did `<p>{state.value}</p>`.